# SVN - committing working copy (svn 1.7.1) to repo (svn 1.6.17)

Tags: svn

I have svn 1.7.1 client locally and have just upgraded my working copy to this. Will my commits cause any issues to the repo for other users of < 1.7.1 clients?

Comment: No. Plus, you should be able to search for this information easily.

Comment: Yeah I thought the same but couldn't actually find it stated as such, nor could I find a duplicate question even though I'm SURE I've seen this answered before. I think it's just obvious to me because upgrading a working copy is a WORKING COPY operation, which by definition makes ZERO repository changes. Combine that with the answer given by Josh that servers and clients always inter-operate across versions and you get that this is perfectly safe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There should not be any issues with your commits.

From
http://subversion.apache.org/docs/release-notes/1.7.html

Permutations of older client/server combinations will continue to function at the pre-1.7 feature level. Server-side configuration changes might be required for optimal performance with clients that use serf.